# entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, foreign-keys

I am trying to save Employee details, which has references with City. But everytime I try to save my contact, which is validated I get the exception **"ADO.Net Entity Framework An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"**

I had read so many post but still not getting the exact idea of what to do...
my Save button click code is given below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService();
        CityService cs = new CityService();

        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 12, 12);
        Payroll.Entities.Employee e1 = new Payroll.Entities.Employee();

        Payroll.Entities.City city1 = cs.SelectCity(Convert.ToInt64(cmbCity.SelectedItem.Value));

        e1.Name = "Archana";
        e1.Title = "aaaa";
        e1.BirthDate = dt;
        e1.Gender = "F";
        e1.HireDate = dt;
        e1.MaritalStatus = "M";
        e1.City = city1;        

        es.AddEmpoyee(e1,city1);
    }
```

and **Employeeservice Code**

```
public string AddEmpoyee(Payroll.Entities.Employee e1, Payroll.Entities.City c1)
        {
            Payroll_DAO1 payrollDAO = new Payroll_DAO1();
            payrollDAO.AddToEmployee(e1);  //Here I am getting Error..
            payrollDAO.SaveChanges();
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
```

Comment: EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService();
CityService cs = new CityService();

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Because these two lines ...

```
EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService();
CityService cs = new CityService();
```

... don't take a parameter in the constructor, I guess that you create a context within the classes. When you load the `city1`...

```
Payroll.Entities.City city1 = cs.SelectCity(...);
```

...you attach the `city1` to the context in `CityService`. Later you add a `city1` as a reference to the new `Employee` `e1` and add `e1` *including this reference to `city1`* to the context in `EmployeeService`. As a result you have `city1` attached to two different context which is what the exception complains about.

You can fix this by creating a context outside of the service classes and injecting and using it in both services:

```
EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService(context);
CityService cs = new CityService(context); // same context instance
```

Your service classes look a bit like repositories which are responsible for only a single entity type. In such a case you will always have trouble as soon as relationships between entities are involved when you use separate contexts for the services.

You can also create a single service which is responsible for a set of closely related entities, like an `EmployeeCityService` (which has a single context) and delegate the whole operation in your `Button1_Click` method to a method of this service.

Comment: I like the way you figured it out even if answer didn't include some background information.

Comment: Looks like this will solve my problem, I just have no idea how to write the new context instance :(

Comment: Abstracting ORM is like putting yellow lipstick on a turd.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but in some ORMs (especially EntityFramework) the data context should always be shortlived. Introducing a static or re-used context will introduce a whole other set of challenges and problems.

Comment: @Maritim it depends on the usage. In Web Applications, its typically one roundtrip. In Desktop Applications, you might also use one per `Form` (what ever, it just represents one unit of work) per `Thread` (because `DbContext` is not guaranteed to be threadsafe).

Comment: Ah, so is a valid summary "don't cross the streams"? All linking needs to be on one instance or the other?

Comment: Does that mean the context has a lifespan at minimum equal to the sum of `EmployeeService` and `CityService` ? Isn't long-running `DbContext` frowned upon ?

Answer (score 36):

Steps to reproduce can be simplified to this:

```cs
var contextOne = new EntityContext();
var contextTwo = new EntityContext();

var user = contextOne.Users.FirstOrDefault();

var group = new Group();
group.User = user;

contextTwo.Groups.Add(group);
contextTwo.SaveChanges();
```

Code without error:

```cs
var context = new EntityContext();

var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault();

var group = new Group();
group.User = user; // Be careful when you set entity properties. 
// Be sure that all objects came from the same context

context.Groups.Add(group);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Using only one `EntityContext` can solve this. Refer to other answers for other solutions.

Comment: lets say you wanted to use contextTwo? (maybe due to scope issues or something) how do you detach from contextOne and attach to contextTwo?

Comment: If you need to do smth like this, most likely you are doing this in wrong way... I suggest using one context.

Comment: There are instances where you would want to use a different instance, such as when pointing into a different database.

Comment: This is a helpful simplification of the problem; but it does not provide a real answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old thread, but another solution, which I prefer, is just update the cityId and not assign the hole model City to Employee... to do that Employee should look like:

```cs
public class Employee{
    ...
    public int? CityId; //The ? is for allow City nullable
    public virtual City City;
}
```

Then it's enough assigning:

```cs
e1.CityId=city1.ID;
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to injection and even worse Singleton, you can call **Detach** method before Add.

EntityFramework 6: `((IObjectContextAdapter)cs).ObjectContext.Detach(city1);`

EntityFramework 4: `cs.Detach(city1);`

There is yet another way, in case you don't need first DBContext object. Just wrap it with **using** keyword:

```
Payroll.Entities.City city1;
using (CityService cs = new CityService())
{
  city1 = cs.SelectCity(Convert.ToInt64(cmbCity.SelectedItem.Value));
}
```

Comment: I used the following: `dbContext1.Entry(backgroundReport).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached`' to detach and then was able to use `dbContext2.Entry(backgroundReport).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` to update. Worked like a dream

Comment: Yes, Peter. I should mention to mark State as Modified.

Comment: In my application startup (global.asax) logic I was loading up a list of widgets.. a simple list of reference objects I stash into memory. Since I was doing my EF context inside Using statements, I thought there'd be no issue later when my controller got around to assigning those objects into a business graph (hey, that old context is gone, right?) - this answer saved me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but my issue with the @Slauma's solution (although great in certain instances) is that it recommends that I pass the context into the service which implies that the context is available from my controller.  It also forces tight coupling between my controller and service layers.

I'm using Dependency Injection to inject the service/repository layers into the controller and as such do not have access to the context from the controller.

My solution was to have the service/repository layers use the same instance of the context - Singleton.

**Context Singleton Class:**

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx
and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

```cs
public sealed class MyModelDbContextSingleton
{
  private static readonly MyModelDbContext instance = new MyModelDbContext();

  static MyModelDbContextSingleton() { }

  private MyModelDbContextSingleton() { }

  public static MyModelDbContext Instance
  {
    get
    {
      return instance;
    }
  }
}
```

**Repository Class:**

```cs
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
  MyModelDbContext context = MyModelDbContextSingleton.Instance;
  [...]
```

Other solutions do exist such as instantiating the context once and passing it into the constructors of your service/repository layers or another I read about which is implementing the Unit of Work pattern.  I'm sure there are more...

Comment: ...doesn't this break down as soon as you try and use multithreading?

Comment: A context should not remain open any longer than necessary, using a Singleton to keep it open forever is the very last thing you want to do.

Comment: I have seen good implementations of this per request. Using the Static keyword is wrong but if you make this pattern to instantiate the context at the beginning of the request and dispose it at the end of request, it would be a legit solution.

Comment: This is really bad advice.  If you're using DI (I don't see the evidence here?) then you should let your DI container manage the context lifetime and it should probably be per-request.

Comment: Supporting comments above. This solution has side effects.

Comment: This is BAD.  BAD. BAD.  BAD. BAD.  Particularly if this is a web application, since static objects are shared between all threads and users.  This means that multiple simultaneous users of your website will be stomping on your data context, potentially corrupting it, saving changes you didn't intend, or even just creating random crashes.  DbContexts should NEVER be shared across threads.  Then there's the problem that statics never get destroyed, so it will sit and keep using more and more memory...

Comment: Great feedback. What do you think of @Aidin's suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using the ASP.NET Identity Framework. I had used the built in `UserManager.FindByNameAsync` method to retrieve an `ApplicationUser` entity. I then tried to reference this entity on a newly created entity on a different `DbContext`. This resulted in the exception you originally saw.

I solved this by creating a new `ApplicationUser` entity with only the `Id` from the `UserManager` method and referencing that new entity.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this same problem after implementing IoC for a project (ASP.Net MVC EF6.2).

Usually I would initialise a data context in the constructor of a controller and use the same context to initialise all my repositories.

However using IoC to instantiate the repositories caused them all to have separate contexts and I started getting this error.

For now I've gone back to just newing up the repositories with a common context while I think of a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I encountered this issue. First I need to save my `Order` which needs a reference to my `ApplicationUser` table:

```
  ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
  user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

  Order entOrder = new Order();
  entOrder.ApplicationUser = user; //I need this user before saving to my database using EF
```

The problem is that I am initializing a new ApplicationDbContext to save my new `Order` entity:

```
 ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
 db.Entry(entOrder).State = EntityState.Added;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

So in order to solve the problem, I used the same ApplicationDbContext instead of using the built-in UserManager of ASP.NET MVC.

Instead of this:

```
user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

I used my existing ApplicationDbContext instance:

```
//db instance here is the same instance as my db on my code above.
user = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could solve making a new instance of the object that I was trying to Update. Then I passed that object to my reposotory.

Comment: Can you please help with sample code. ? so it will be clear what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it turns out the error is very clear: Entity Framework cannot track an entity using multiple instances of `IEntityChangeTracker` or typically, multiple instances of `DbContext`. The solutions are: use one instance of `DbContext`; access all needed entities through a single repository (depending on one instance of `DbContext`); or turning off tracking for all entities accessed via a repository other than the one throwing this particular exception.

When following an inversion of control pattern in .Net Core Web API, I frequently find that I have controllers with dependencies such as:

```
private readonly IMyEntityRepository myEntityRepo; // depends on MyDbContext
private readonly IFooRepository fooRepo; // depends on MyDbContext
private readonly IBarRepository barRepo; // depends on MyDbContext
public MyController(
    IMyEntityRepository myEntityRepo, 
    IFooRepository fooRepo, 
    IBarRepository barRepo)
{
    this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
    this.barRepo = barRepo;
    this.myEntityRepo = myEntityRepo;
}
```

and usage like

```
...
myEntity.Foo = await this.fooRepository.GetFoos().SingleOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == model.FooId);
if (model.BarId.HasValue)
{
    myEntity.Foo.Bar = await this.barRepository.GetBars().SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == model.BarId.Value);
}

...
await this.myEntityRepo.UpdateAsync(myEntity); // this throws an error!
```

Since all three repositories depend on different `DbContext` instances per request, I have two options to avoid the problem and maintain separate repositories: change the injection of the DbContext to create a new instance only once per call:

```
// services.AddTransient<DbContext, MyDbContext>(); <- one instance per ctor. bad
services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>(); // <- one instance per call. good!
```

or, if the child entity is being used in a read-only manner, turning off tracking on that instance:

```
myEntity.Foo.Bar = await this.barRepo.GetBars().AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == model.BarId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same DBContext object throughout the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario we have a solution with several applications referencing the same context. I had to update the unity.config file adding lifetime type to the context.

```
<lifetime type="PerResolveLifetimeManager" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Error source:

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.Name);
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContent();
db.Users.Uploads.Add(new MyUpload{FileName="newfile.png"});
await db.SavechangesAsync();/ZZZZZZZ
```

Hope someone saves some precious time

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  Perhaps some context would help.