# Is Disposing of Entity Framework context object required

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework

We are using entity framework for communication with database in our WCF service methods, recently we run the code review tool on our service code. As usual we got many review proposals by tool and many review comments were suggesting to dispose the Entity Framework context object. So, my question is if I use a Entity Framework context object within a method and once I come out of the method, GC doesn't clean up the context object ? do we need to explicitly dispose context object ?

Comment: How do you use it now? I usually use the context within a using block.

Comment: Currently it is without using block.

Comment: Keep it without a using, the using will kill off potential threads launched from within it, as the context will be possibly disposed before reaching the end of the thread launched form within it.

Comment: I think a key point was missed in many of the answers,  that is that DBContext is often used with DependencyInjection (in MVC).  In that case  the DBContext is NOT created by the service class, but is injected by the framework.  In this case it should NOT be disposed in the service class since it was not created within the class.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply: [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) implements `IDisposable`, therefore you should dispose of it, manually, as soon as you're done with it.

You don't *need* to dispose of it, because the GC will collect it eventually, but the GC isn't deterministic: you never know when "eventually" will be. Until it's disposed, it will be holding resources that aren't in use - for example, it may still have an open database connection. Those resources aren't freed until the GC runs, *unless* you dispose manually. Depending on specific details you may find that you have unnecessarily blocked network resources, file accesses, and you will certainly be keeping more memory reserved than you need to.

There's a further potential hit, too: when you dispose of an object manually, the GC doesn't typically need to call the Finalizer on that object (if there is one). If you leave the GC to automatically dispose of an object with a Finalizer, it'll place the object in a Finalizer Queue - and will automatically promote the object to the next GC generation. This means that an object with a finalizer will always hang around for orders of magnitude longer than it needs to before being GCed (as successive GC generations are collected less frequently). `DBContext` would likely fall into this category as the underlying database connection will be unmanaged code.

(Useful [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#what_happens_during_a_garbage_collection).)

Comment: Is question about GC and IDisposable purpose, or it is specific about DbContext?

Comment: The question is specific to `DbContext`, but the answer is that `DbContext` is susceptible to exactly the same best practise as every other `IDisposable` for exactly the same reasons as every otherr `IDisposable` - hence the mostly-generic answer.

Comment: That's up to OP and those who upvoted this answer. I don't see anything specific to DbContext here. No explanation of what kind of resources should be released.

Comment: I don't understand your objection. The answers to the OP's specific questions are: yes the GC will dispose of a `DbContext`, but you don't know when (as per the start of my second paragraph), and yes you should explicitly dispose (as per my first sentence). The rest of the answer is background and detail to explain why this is important (for *any* `IDisposable`). The specific details of `DbContext` aren't particularly relevant to the answer as they wouldn't *change* the answer (and are an implementation detail of black-box code anyway).

Comment: Actually it looks like you dont have to dispose DBcontext (by design) http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U6WdzrGEeTw

Answer (score 10):

I think the best approach is coding it within a using statement

```
using(var cx = new DbContext())
{
  //your stuff here
}
```

so it got automaitaclly disposed

Comment: If we use this approach how can we mock out the DBContext to write Unit tests?

Comment: Look up the Repository and unit of work pattern http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: what to do, if I want to use the context classwide? (create it in the constructor - how and where to close it?)

Comment: Avoid creating new Context's (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)

Answer (score 3):

In general if something implements `IDisposable` it's a Good Idea(TM) to explicitly dispose of it when you're through. This is especially true if you do not own the implementation of said object; you should treat it as a black box in this case. Additionally, even if it were not necessarily "required" to dispose of it now, it may be in the future.

Therefore, IMHO the question of whether you "need to" explicitly dispose of the object is irrelevant. If it is asking to be disposed of - by virtue of implementing `IDisposable` - it should be disposed of.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended thing to do with a DBContext is to not dispose of it at all (it is the exception to the rule in most cases), even though is a disposable object.

An example of the issue, ths first example is taking a call and evaluation it in the using statement, while the second evaluates it after. (first ons runs, second one throws error `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`)

```
List<Test> listT;
using (Model1 db = new Model1())
{
    listT = db.Tests.ToList(); //ToList Evaluates
}
foreach (var a in listT)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.value);
}

IEnumerable<Test> listT1;
using (Model1 db = new Model1())
{
    listT1 = db.Tests;
}
foreach (var a in listT1) //foreach evaluates (but at wrong time)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.value);
}
```

The same issue happens in

```
IEnumerable<Test> listT1;
Model1 db = new Model1();
listT1 = db.Tests;
db.Dispose();
foreach (var a in listT1) //foreach evaluates (but at wrong time)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.value);
}
```

Aslong as you dont open the connection manually you are safe by just using

```
IEnumerable<Test> listT1;
Model1 db = new Model1();
listT1 = db.Tests;
foreach (var a in listT1) //foreach evaluates (but at wrong time)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.value);
}
```

and never disposing. as it will take care of itself under most circumstances, as thats what it's designed to do.

Now should you open up a connection by force then the context wont close it automatically when the transfer is done, as it don't know when and then you must/should dispose the object or close the connection and keep the object undisclosed.

Extra midnight reading:

1. http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U6WdzrGEeTw
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to explicitly dispose DbContext.

This is an old hold over from pre-DbContext tools. DbContext is managed code and optimistically maintains database connections on its own. Why sledgehammer it? Whats the hurry? Why not just let the garbage collector decide the best time to clean up when the machine is idle or in need of memory? Also refer to this post: https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/

By not worrying about having to dispose will simplify and optimize your code. Typically I might inherit from a database "helper" class to where I use a getter to either return an already existing DbContext instance, or instantiates a new instance. .

```
public class DataTools
{
    private AppContext _context;
    protected AppContext Context => _context ?? (_context = new AppContext());
}

pubic class YourApp : DataTools
{
    public void DoLotsOfThings()
    {
        var = Context.SomeTable.Where(s => s.....);
        var stuff = GetSomeThing();
       foreach(){}
    }

    Public string GetSomething()
    {
        return Context.AnotherTable.First(s => s....).Value;
    }
}
```