# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. Wi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, usermanager

```
namespace BoatShop.Controllers
{
    public class ManagerController : Controller
    {
    ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
    public ManagerController()
    {
        dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public ManagerController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {return View();}

    public ActionResult ViewBoats()
    {
        var allBoats = dbContext.Boats.Where(x => x.isArchived == false).ToList();
        return View(allBoats);
    }

    public ActionResult MakeOrder(int boatId)
    {
        OrderViewModel model = new OrderViewModel
        {
            boatId = boatId,
            boatName = dbContext.Boats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == boatId).Name,
            ManagerName = User.Identity.Name,
            userList = dbContext.Users.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MakeOrder(OrderViewModel model)
    {
        model.Order.Boat = dbContext.Boats.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==model.boatId);
        ApplicationUser seller = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ApplicationUser customer = UserManager.FindById(model.CustomerId);
        model.Order.SalePerson = seller;
        model.Order.Customer = customer;
        model.Order.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        var order = model.Order;
        dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

By trial-and-error i have found out that error is caused by

```
model.Order.SalePerson = seller; model.Order.Customer = customer;
```

those lines. I think i need to detach those out of usermanager somehow, but i have no clue how. How can i solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are merging entities from 2 different instances of a DbContext.

- The `UserManager` from which the seller and customer, has its own instance.
- The `dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext()` in the constructor of the controller.

You need to use the same instance. There are many ways to do this. One of them being dependency injection.

Or, based on your code, I guess that you could just call:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This will give you the same instance of the DbContext as the UserManager but I think you can't call it in the constructor. You will have to call this in the action function or create a property like the UserManager.