# I have an error message "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" but not sure of suggested solutions

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a user using aspnet.identity and get this error message on

IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

the code it is contained in

```
 protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

    int x = int.Parse(Address.SelectedValue.ToString());
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            physAddress = db.PhysAddress.Find(x);
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text, FirstName = FirstName.Text, LastName = LastName.Text, PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.Text, HomePhone = HomePhone.Text, PhysAddressId = physAddress };

            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

            if (result.Succeeded)....
```

I've tried researching error message but not sure how to apply in this example.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have a class defined as follows and was using db to get a row from that table using EF

```
 public class PhysAddress
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PhysAddressId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
```

And then below ApplicationDbContext in IdentityModels.cs have below

```
  public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public DbSet<PhysAddress> PhysAddress { get; set; }
```

In IdentityModels have added for each user the property

```
        public virtual PhysAddress  PhysAddressId  { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your code does not seem right. Why you have new ApplicationDbContext and then using manager to add the user. Isn't user manager a context itself?

Comment: see additional code posted as to why I was using db

Comment: Do you have the same address entity in your owin context, if so the error is for that, since both context try to track the changes on that address when you add it to the user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)

Comment: the PhysAddressId is an additional user property I've defined in IdentityModels, so is there a different access method I should be using to set this property.  The address ID is obtained from a dropdownlist and I set it using    int x = int.Parse(Address.SelectedValue.ToString()); then I set the physAddress to this row in table Maybe I should be setting it some other way

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by using

```
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Detach(physAddress);
```