# How can I reference an user object in an Entity Framework model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have the following model:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> AssociatedUsers { get; set; }

    public MyEntity()
    {
        AssociatedUsers = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

Notice that each entity has some associated users. In my controller, I'm trying to add an instance of `MyEntity` to the database like this:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// ...

ApplicationUser currentUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

MyEntity entityInstance = new MyEntity();
entityInstance.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
entityInstance.AssociatedUsers.Add(currentUser);
db.MyEntities.Add(entityInstance);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, that code throws the following error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

I gather from that error message that `CurrentUser` is still being managed by the database context which backs the `ApplicationUserManager`, so I can't add it to a different context. But unlike [other cases that I have found documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker), I can't simply switch the context so that they share a database connection: the user object is coming from an `ApplicationUserManager`. What do I need to do to resolve this? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I am aware that I could use the ID instead and look up the corresponding user, but I would rather have the object accessible directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to the problem found in the link you've posted. In a few words, you can't manipulate a user from different contexts. Here:

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

You effectively got `currentUser` from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()`, but then you're trying to save it using `db`, which is an `ApplicationDbContext`.

Keep it on the same context, and you will have your problem solved:

```
var currentUser = db.Users.Find(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

var entityInstance = new MyEntity();

entityInstance.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

entityInstance.AssociatedUsers.Add(currentUser);
db.MyEntities.Add(entityInstance);
db.SaveChanges();
```