# Entities are not updated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-5

I have a strange problem with EntityFraemwork when I want to update entity.
I have User entity and Searchfilter entity, they have one-to-many relationship

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
   public virtual List<SearchFilter> SearchFilters { get; set; }
}

public class SearchFilter : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

1 - I create user
2 - I run method that creates and adds user to searchfilter

```
SearchFilter searchFilter = SearchFilterRepository.AddAsync(new SearchFilter
{
     SearchInDescription = false,
     SearchInTitle = false
 }).Result;
```

I used Result without async that had a test. I thought the problem was in async operations in EF.
Then:

```
 searchFilter.User = user;
 SearchFilterRepository.Update(searchFilter);
```

Update:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    _dbMainContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _dbMainContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

And I have an error: The "PK_AspNetUsers" PRIMARY KEY constraint was violated. Unable to insert duplicate key into dbo.AspNetUsers object. Duplicate key value: (0e535b73-7cff-4152-9157-214b9821d264).
The execution of this instruction has been interrupted.

I think that EF, update SearchFilter and ADD new user, which already exists, how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add UserId property and use it instead of reference User Property

```
public class SearchFilter : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

then use insert or update

```
searchFilter.UserId = /* Add User Guid */;
SearchFilterRepository.Update(searchFilter);
```

Comment: Yes i know it, userid is a hidden property in a model, but i don't want see it in my model, I thought there is another solution

Comment: what do you mean by hidden property ?

Comment: if I create only public virtual User User { get; set; } code first realization create UserId in DB table SearchFilter  and i think have another solution that exclude create UserId property in a model. I have another model in which I do the same, an error falls, but the data is entered

Comment: perhaps you can somehow disable the addition of third-party entities from one entity

Comment: i think to update user you should select complete user object otherwise ef will consider this as new user so you can use userId when update or select full object of user to edit

Comment: this also may help you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787327/how-can-i-reference-an-user-object-in-an-entity-framework-model

Comment: Please tell me what it means to select a complete user object? I create a user and this user I send to my method, which uses it and assigns it SearchFilter

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean, you can show me an example

Comment: Just select the entity from DB then assign this object, could you please share with me your fuction? And are you tried the solution i provided in my answer?

Comment: This will help you https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships/managing-one-to-many-relationships

Comment: Your last answer helped me. Thank You. I do `_dbMainContext.Attach(user); filter.User = user; _dbMainContext.SaveChanges();`