# Error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

friends.
I really need your help. I would be very grateful.

And so I have the entity "Model" c field "ID_model" and "name" in MS SQL Server.
I want, after clicking "Edit" on Form1, there is another form (FormModel) where you can change the data and write changes to the database.

The problem is that after pressing "Edit" there is an error about "Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" And I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Code from Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyDBEntities db2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db2 = new MyDBEntities();
        modelBindingSource.DataSource = db2.Models.ToList();
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (modelBindingSource.Current == null)
            return;
        using (FormModel frm = new FormModel(modelBindingSource.Current as Model))
        {
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                modelBindingSource.DataSource = db2.Models.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from FormModel:

```
public partial class FormModel : Form
{
    MyDBEntities db2;
    public FormModel(Model obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        db2 = new MyDBEntities();
        if (obj == null)
        {
            modelBindingSource.DataSource = new Model();
            db2.Models.Add(modelBindingSource.Current as Model);
        }
        else
        {
            modelBindingSource.DataSource = obj;
            db2.Models.Attach(modelBindingSource.Current as Model);
        }
    }

    private void FormModel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtModelName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are empty fields", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtModelName.Focus();
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            db2.SaveChanges();
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

I really hope help. All the best. And excuse me for my English.

Comment: You are attaching the same item to more than 1 context and that is not allowed. This is how you get the error. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't know how fix that in my situation. I looked your link, but it's don't helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Form1` you have this code (note I have replaced some code with comments for brevity):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // code...
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code...
        modelBindingSource.DataSource = db2.Models.ToList();
        // code...
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code...
        using (FormModel frm = new FormModel(modelBindingSource.Current as Model))
        {
            // code...
        }
    }
}
```

The code `modelBindingSource.DataSource = db2.Models.ToList();` is setting the `DataSource` property to `Models`. Everything in `Models` is loaded from the database; in other words, the `db2` context has everything in `Models`. You just got it from `db2` so it must be there.

The code `using (FormModel frm = new FormModel(modelBindingSource.Current as Model))` is sending the `Model` to the `FormModel` constructor.

Then in `FormModel`, you have this code:

```
public partial class FormModel : Form
{
    MyDBEntities db2;
    public FormModel(Model obj)
    {
        db2 = new MyDBEntities();
        // code...
        db2.Models.Attach(modelBindingSource.Current as Model);
    }

    // code...
}
```

See in the above code you are attaching the `Model` to a new context named `db2` but since `Model` is already attached to `db2` in `Form1`, the exception is thrown and it is clearly telling you this:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

The message could not be any clearer than that.

---

**Fix**

Remove this line of code `db2.Models.Attach(modelBindingSource.Current as Model);` so you are not attaching it. Not sure why you are doing that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach) answer for why and when you need to call `Attach`.

---

**Clean Up**

Actually from the code you have posted, the `obj` in `FormModel` constructor can never be null so this is all the code you need in `FormModel`:

```
public partial class FormModel : Form
{
    public FormModel(Model obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        modelBindingSource.DataSource = obj;
    }

    private void FormModel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtModelName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Есть пустые поля", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtModelName.Focus();
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call `SaveChanges` in your `Form1` like this:

```
using (FormModel frm = new FormModel(modelBindingSource.Current as Model))
{
    if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        modelBindingSource.DataSource = db2.Models.ToList(); // not sure if you need this
        db2.SaveChanges(); // <-- call save here since the dialog has been closed.
    }
}
```

**Additional Notes**

Just a final note, `FormModel` and `Form1` are not good names for forms. Good names for forms should show the intention of the form. For example, names like `OrderEntryForm`, `OrderDetailForm` etc. are good names.