# How to insert two different object into the database but check if they already exists throws `InvalidOperationException`?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

### Situation sketch

---

I develop a system where there many materials *(in code `Matetiaal`)* could be added to an advertisement *(in code `Zoeker`)*. The relationship is many to many. Here you got the structure of my classes.

```
+-------------------------------------+   many to many   +-------------------------------+
|                Zoeker               | <--------------> |           Materiaal           |
+------------+------------------------+                  +---------+---------------------+
| ID         | int                    |                  | ID      | int                 |
| Materialen | ICollection<Materiaal> |                  | Zoekers | ICollection<Zoeker> |
| Titel      | string                 |                  | Naam    | string              |
+------------+------------------------+                  +---------+---------------------+
```

I'll add new materials and advertisements using next pseudo code:

```csharp
void Insert(Zoeker zoeker, string[] materialen) 
{
    foreach (string m in materialen)
    {
        Materiaal mat = materiaalRepo.GetByName(m);

        if (mat == null)
        {
            mat = materiaalRepo.Insert(new Materiaal(m));
        }

        zoeker.Materialen.Add(mat);
    }

    zoekerRepo.Insert(zoeker);
}
```

In words when a new advertisement *(`Zoeker`)* must be added, I'll check if the material already exist in the database. The method `materialenRepo.GetByName(string)` returns `null` if the material doesn't exists. If that is true, insert a new material into the database and returns the `Materiaal`-object. After that or if `materialenRepo.GetByName(string)` didn't return a `null`, add that material to the `Materialen`-property of the advertisement and insert that into the database.

To connect the database with my application I use Entity Framework.

### My problem

---

When I use the code on heading below, I've got this exception:

> **`System.InvalidOperationException`:** An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of `IEntityChangeTracker`.
>
> ```csharp
> public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
> {
>     return dbSet.Add(entity); // <-- on this line
> }
> ```

The exception is thrown on the marked line when `zoekerRepo.Insert(zoeker);` is called.

### My code

---

Here you could find my code I've made.

#### Service

```csharp
public class ZoekService
{
    public int InsertZoeker(Zoeker zoeker, ApplicationUser user, string materialenString)
    {
        return InsertZoeker(zoeker, user, materialenString.Split(','));
    }

    public int InsertZoeker(Zoeker zoeker, ApplicationUser user, string[] materialen)
    {
        zoeker.Gebruiker = user;
        zoeker.Materialen = new List<Materiaal>();

        using (ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            ZoekerRepository zoekerRepo = new ZoekerRepository(ctx);
            MateriaalRepository materiaalRepo = new MateriaalRepository(ctx); 
            // ^^^^ See update one

            foreach (string m in materialen)
            {
                Materiaal materiaal = materiaalRepo.GetByNaam(m);

                if (materiaal == null)
                {
                    materiaal = materiaalRepo.Insert(new Materiaal(m)); 
                    // ^ See update three
                }

                zoeker.Materialen.Add(materiaal);
            }

            zoekerRepo.Insert(zoeker); 
            zoekerRepo.SaveChanges(); // <-- Pointer didn't come on this line.

            return zoeker.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Repositories

**`ZoekerRepository` extends `GenericRepository<Zoeker>`**

```csharp
public class ZoekerRepository : GenericRepository<Zoeker>
{
    public ZoekerRepository()
    { }

    public ZoekerRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx): base(ctx)
    { }

    // Some other methods I've add or will override.
}
```

**`MateriaalRepository` extends `GenericRepository<Materiaal>`**

```csharp
public class MateriaalRepository : GenericRepository<Materiaal>
{
    public MateriaalRepository()
    { }

    public MateriaalRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx): base(ctx)
    { }

    public Materiaal GetByNaam(string naam)
    {
        return (from m in dbSet
                where m.Naam.Equals(naam)
                select m).SingleOrDefault<Materiaal>();
    }

    // Some other methods I've add or will override.
}
```

**`GenericRepository<TEntity>`**

```csharp
public class GenericRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{ 
    internal ApplicationDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepo()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public GenericRepo(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        return dbSet.Add(entity); // <-- after `zoekerRepo.Insert(Zoeker)` the exception
                                  //       will be thrown on this line.
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

### What I've done

---

Of course I've tried other code but all code gives the same exception. I'll make my code so that the repository for the materials is separated with the repository from the advertisements repository using the same generic class named `GenericRepo<TEntity>` *(except from the thing I'll add or override)*. I'll reuse that as most as possible. Once for `GenericRepo<Zoeker>` and an other time for `GenericRepo<Materiaal>`.

### My question

---

How could I solve this bug?

### Update one

---

This question is not duplicate with [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker) because I use the same context like the accepted answer said:

> You can fix this by creating a context outside of the service classes and injecting and using it in both services:
>
> ```csharp
> EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService(context);
> CityService cs = new CityService(context); // same context instance
> ```

See the comments on code above.

### Update two

---

Here you've a new part of my code I've made.

#### Controllers

```csharp
public class DeelController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }
    private ZoekService _zoekservice = new ZoekService();

    public DeelController()
    {
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ApplicationDbContext));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Nieuw()
    {
        return View(new Zoeker());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Nieuw(Zoeker zoeker)
    {
        _zoekservice.InsertZoeker(zoeker, await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name), zoeker.MaterialenString);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

#### Classes

**`Zoeker` extends `Post`**

```csharp
public class Zoeker: Post
{
    public virtual ICollection<Materiaal> Materialen { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Delers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string MaterialenString { get; set; } // <-- contains a comma separated
                                                 //       list of all materials
}
```

**`Post`**

```csharp
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Gebruiker { get; set; }
    public string GebruikerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartPeriode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Verwijderd { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? Opgelost { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? Belangerijk { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Antwoord> Antwoorden { get; set; }
}
```

### Update three

---

I've also tried to replace the commented line from code above with this code but didn't solve this bug:

```csharp
materiaal = /*materiaalRepo.Insert(*/ new Materiaal(m); //);
```

If I use a material that doesn't exists, using the code of update three, I've got the bug again.

### Update four

---

If I use the watcher I see this:

[image: Watchers shows a field _entityWrapper for the existing material]

`Material[0]` got a field `_entityWrapper` type of `EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships<System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Materiaal_E0DDEFDA63D33C75C64324662B40FDC414EC19CA4AD6BF18443B63FC60015374>`. **Note:** This material does already exists in the database. Also here I've got the same bug.

### Update five

I've also replaced the `InsertZoeker(Zoeker

```csharp
public int InsertZoeker(Zoeker zoeker, ApplicationUser user, string[] materialen)
{
    Zoeker newZoeker = new Zoeker()
    {
        Gebruiker = user,
        StartPeriode = DateTime.Now,
        Materialen = new List<Materiaal>(),
        Titel = zoeker.Titel,
        Omschrijving = zoeker.Omschrijving
    };

    using (ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        ZoekerRepository zoekerRepo = new ZoekerRepository(ctx);
        MateriaalRepository materiaalRepo = new MateriaalRepository(ctx);

        foreach (string m in materialen)
        {
            Materiaal materiaal = materiaalRepo.GetMateriaalByNaam(m);

            if (materiaal == null)
            {
                materiaal = /*materiaalRepo.Insert(*/ new Materiaal(m); //);
            }

            newZoeker.Materialen.Add(materiaal);
        }

        zoekerRepo.Insert(newZoeker);
        zoekerRepo.SaveChanges();

        return zoeker.ID;
    }
}
```

[image: Can you do anything right?]

Comment: The question is though, where `Zoeker zoeker` comes from? Looks like it's attached to another `DbContext` instance.

Comment: I second @IvanStoev comment. Your method parameter is a `zoeker` that exists before the `zoekerRepo` of the current instance is created. So its origin is potentially important.

Comment: Still not clear where that `zoeker` comes. I suppose it comes from controller (as controller parameter) but then it goes to some `DeelService` first, not to ZoekerService

Comment: The last update clearly indicates that `zoeker` is a proxy attached to another context. You need to create a new `Zoeker` instance, copy the properties and pass that instance to the repository `Insert` method.

Comment: Since (as you state) the problem is caused by code thats not part of the question, I vote to close as *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced*

Answer (score 1):

Stupid from me I was using an other context for get the user inside my `DeelController`. I've deleted that code inside my question.

@mjwills: it's indeed a duplicate question.

@everyone_else: I'm sorry that I've done that.