# How to solve one to many tables relations An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker error

Tags: entity

Consider the following code:

```
var courseName=DbContext.SingleInstance().Entities.tblCourse.ToList();
DbContext.SingleInstance().Entities.ChangeDatabase(ECourse.SingleInstance.CourseNameTable);
DbContext.SingleInstance().CourseEntities.tblCourse.AddRange(courseName);
DbContext.SingleInstance().CourseEntities.SaveChanges();
```

**DbContext.SingleInstance().CourseEntities.tblCourse.AddRange(courseName);**

This row is **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker error.**

`tblCourse` is relations one to many other tables.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *Be sure to research your error and question before you ask it.* Often you'll find an answer before you finish writing your question. For instance, I googled `IEntityChangeTracker error` just to see what language you were talking about, and I found [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker) with the same error as yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)