# Table contains only two foreign keys. But its not showing in EDMX model using database first approach Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

These are my model classes

[image]I have three tables [image]

But when I update my model, the `PurchaseReturnDetail` table is not there in the model, and it creates a one-to-many relationship between `PurchaseReturn` and `PurchaseDetail`.

I'm using repository pattern and I don't know how to insert transactions in `PurchaseReturnDetail` table.

Following is my code to insert transaction. but it gives exception

> Message = "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

```
 public async Task<Response> SaveAsync(PurchaseReturn purchaseReturn, List<string> serialNoList)
    {
        PurchaseReturnRepository rep = new PurchaseReturnRepository();

        decimal totalRate = 0;
        foreach (var serialNo in serialNoList)
        {
            var purchaseDetail = await PurchaseService.Instance.GetSinglePurchasedItemDetailAsync(serialNo);

            purchaseReturn.PurchaseDetails.Add(purchaseDetail);

            //Calculating total rate to update supplier balance
            totalRate += purchaseDetail.Rate;


        }

        var response = await rep.AddAsync(purchaseReturn);

        if (response.Success)
        {
            //Updating Supplier Balance
            response = await SupplierService.Instance.UpdataBalanceAsync(purchaseReturn.SupplierId, totalRate, false);
            response.Msg = "Items has beed returned and stock is updated";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

**NOTE** : I'm using database first approach

Comment: Show your model classes please? Give the screenshot database table's column list.

Comment: Did you intentionally undo the seemingly helpful formatting changes by another user? Be careful with that. What are your reasons for that? Formatting which is perceived as "noisy" is not to your benefit. If it was unintenionally I will be happy to help with some explanation or hints.

Comment: #Yunnosch yes please

Comment: The two FKs should both form a composite PK. Then EF will model this as many-many with a hidden junction class.

Comment: Please don't add new questions. What's the use anyway of writing code when the model isn't right? I'd rather see you respond to my previous comment.

Comment: #GertArnold what do you suggest me to do? I know Entity Framework does not generate model for table which only have foreign keys. But my requirement is obvious, I don't want any thing else in relational table except foreign keys

Comment: Did you understand what I said about the primary key? Both FK fields in `PurchaseReturnDetail` should be one composite primary key. Fix that first and then regenerate the model. Also, if you know that EF doesn't generate a class for tables with foreign keys only then why do you phrase your question as though you seem surprised it's not there?

Comment: Both foreign keys are now composite key  in `PurchaseReturnDetail` and regenerated the model. Now model is showing many-many relation between `PurchaseDetail` and `PurchaseReturn`. But when I run insert query it gives my exception `Message = "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."`

Comment: And that's a different problem, not related to the shape of the model. You have a static context, which is against all recommendations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)