# Insert Multiple Records in Foreign key table - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to insert multiple records in a table who have Foreign Key column but unable to insert values in a foreign key column.
Following is the screen shot of the table Structure:

[image]

I've created a form where user can enter multiple records in `AllocationsDetailedForecast` table with certain combinations of Date/Variant & SalesExecutive. Only DealerQty column is editable to the user while all others are being readonly.

Following is the code of my Controller where I am trying to Save Values in The database:

```
  string allocationPeriod = allocation.AllocationMonth;

    AllocationsDetailedForecast forecast = new AllocationsDetailedForecast();
    forecast.ForecastDate = allocation.ForecastDate;

//****Here I'm trying to get the object of SalesExecutive by using the ID recieved from the View
        forecast.SalesExecutive = db.SalesExecutive.Find(allocation.SalesExecutive_id);
        forecast.VariantCode = allocation.VariantCode;            
        forecast.DealerQty = allocation.DealerQty;
        forecast.AllocationMonth = allocationPeriod;

        forecast.DealerName = dealerName;            
        forecast.AllocationsForecastSetup = forecastSetup;


      db.AllocationsDetailedForecast.Add(forecast);
```

I am getting the following error while inserting the record:

```
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'**
```

Please Help me resolve this, How can I pass salesExecutiveID during Insertion as a Foreign key

Comment: _uow where this variable is coming from ?

Comment: same entity object is used in multiple dbContexts, you are using one `db.SalesExecutive.Find(allocation.SalesExecutive_id);` and other probably in your `uow`, you should be loading `SalesExecutive` via `ùow` or `Repository` not directly on the dbContext

Comment: @DIlshodK this was the repository reference, please see my update, I've now directly tried adding the object still the error is same

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Please see my update, uow is just a class having the references of all the tables and some general functions, I've now directly tried adding the object to db, still the error is same

Comment: @AlinaAnjum What about `forecast.AllocationsForecastSetup = forecastSetup` line? Does forecastSetup  has the same context?

Comment: @AlinaAnjum try changing the line `forecast.SalesExecutive = db.SalesExecutive.Find(allocation.SalesExecutive_id);`to : `forecast.SalesExecutive_id = allocation.SalesExecutive_id;` and `forecast.AllocationsForecastSetup = forecastSetup;` to : `forecast.ForeCastSetupID = forecastSetup.ID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are trying to create association between entities with different contexts. You are inserting `AllocationsDetailedForecast` in `_uow` context and associating it with `SalesExecutive`

`forecast.SalesExecutive = db.SalesExecutive.Find(allocation.SalesExecutive_id);`

which its context is `db`. Try to add your `forecast` to `db` variable. Check answer of Pavel Shkleinik in [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)

**EDIT:**

Also, make sure `forecastSetup` entity has the same context with `forecast` in this line:

```
forecast.AllocationsForecastSetup = forecastSetup
```

Comment: I've tried db.AllocationsDetailedForecast.Add(forecast);, please see my update

Comment: yes this was the context issue, the contexts fore forecastsetup, salesexecutive were diffrent, thanks